# Match integer or integer+

Tags: php, regex

I have a select box:

```
<select name="count">
    <option value="0">Select count</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    ..
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="5+">5+</option>
</select>
```

So I want to check if the value is an integer or `5+`.

I tried:

```
$pattern = '/^[0-9]*?[0-9+]$/';
$count = '1';

if(preg_match($pattern, $count)){
    echo 'Valid';
}else{
    echo 'Invalid';
}
```

That returns `Valid`.

```
$count = '10+';
```

That also returns `Valid`.

But not sure if that's working well or not.

Is it checking integer or integer+?

I want to check for an integer or 5+ only.

Comment: Do you mean `'/^(?:\d+|5\+)$/'`?

Comment: If you just want to check if it is 5+ or not why not simply `if ($count != '5+')` etc?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, Yes that's working, Please submit an answer explaining the pattern

Comment: @Dave, I want to check for an integer `1 2 3 ..` or `+5`

Comment: @Bon I posted the answer with explanation.

Comment: @bon something as simple as `if (ctype_digit($count) OR $count != '5+')` should work for you then without needing regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use

```
'~^(?:\d+|5\+)$~D'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/CfijxQ/2)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:` - a [non-capturing group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group-what-does-do) that matches either of the two patterns:

  - `\d+`  - one or more digits
  - `|` - or
  - `5\+` - `5+` substring
- `)` - end of the group
- `$` - the very end of the string (since [`PCRE_DOLLAR_ENDONLY`](http://php.net/manual/fa/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) `D` modifier does not allow `$` to match before the final newline char in the string).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use

```
$pattern = '/^\d+\+?$/';
```

Comment: The pattern is checking for integers or integer+, But I want to specify the part of `integer+` to `5+` only or an integer like `1 2 3 ..`

Comment: Then use `'/^\d+|5\+$/`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `^\d+(\+?)$` to allow for `+` after any digit.

```
$pattern = '/^\d+(\+?)$/';
preg_match($pattern, '1'); // Match
preg_match($pattern, '5+'); // Match
preg_match($pattern, '10+'); // Match
```

If you only want to allow for `5+` specifically then `^(\d+|5\+)$` should do the job.

```
$pattern = '/^(\d+|5\+)$/';
preg_match($pattern, '1'); // Match
preg_match($pattern, '5+'); // Match
preg_match($pattern, '10+'); // No match
```

You can see both of the above working [in a sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/2ac30e0ef56c2326545df1c8b78450957b3aa937).